# MongoDB save() - showing "..." after command is run

Tags: mongodb, command-line, save

Some data was imported into a MongoDB collection, but it went in as follows:

```
{
 "pid": "702000",
 "source" : 510,
 "address" : "123 Fake St",
 "Postcode" : "187\"",
 [.. etc ..]
 "_id" : 123456
}
```

I need to remove the \" from the postcode bit, so in the mongo command line I did:

```
db.members.save({
 "pid": "702000",
 "source" : 510,
 "address" : "123 Fake St",
 "Postcode" : "187",
 [.. etc ..]
 "_id" : 123456
})
```

.. just removed the slash and extra double quotes.

After running the command, the terminal goes to the next line with 3 periods:
"..." and stays there - mongo prompt does not return.

If I exit out of the command, the save() does not take place.

How might I run this save command properly?

Is there another command that needs running in there, something like "\g" to carry out multi-line commands as in MySQL server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ah. From: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/EdxJxh-QkjY

"Three '.'s means your statement isn't complete...  Most likely, you've missed a closing curly brace.  Check your syntax"

There was another key pair in the array that had '\"' in it, causing the problem. Once removed  the command ran fine.